# How do I add a Checkbox to a tool bar in MFC with a custom bitmap?

Tags: c++, mfc

I have a C++ MFC MDI application. I have a tool bar with some buttons on it. I need to add some check boxes to this toolbar and i need them to have custom bitmaps just as my buttons do. Thanks

EDIT:
By bitmpas i refer to the pixel images that can be created using the tool bar editor in visual stuidos 2008. I would like a picture (of my creation) instead of the usual tick box.

Comment: Please provide more info/an example/a mockup of what you want to achieve. Like this, people are not likely to know what you mean by: "i need them to have custom bitmaps just as my buttons do"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't use checkboxes on toolbars.

You should rather use regular buttons in *Check* mode. That means that the button stays pressed when user releases it. Clicking it a second time releases the button. This is the same behaviour as a checkbox.

You can either set a toolbar button as *checkable* by code:

```
m_ToolBar.SetButtonStyle(nButtonId, TBBS_CHECKBOX);
```

Or by enabling the corresponding property in the resource editor.

If you want to modify the image displayed when the button is pressed, in your [`ON_UPDATE_COMMAND_UI`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b8c866kb%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) handler, use m_ToolBar.GetButtonInfo() to check if the image matches the state. If not, change it using [`m_ToolBar.SetButtonInfo()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/477kf668%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and specify the index of an extra image added to the image list of the toolbar.

Comment: Im getting a debug assertion failure when calling setbuttonstyle and the debugger is breaking on 'VERIFY(pBar->DefWindowProc(TB_GETBUTTON, nIndex, (LPARAM)pButton));'

Comment: Thanks this is very helpful and much simpler when compared to using send message: `m_wndToolBar.SendMessage(TB_CHECKBUTTON, ID_BUTTON, FALSE);` to check and uncheck. Only thing is, the index of my button seems to be offset from what i would expect it to be. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The following is a link which might help you

http://www.ucancode.net/Visual_C_Control/Place-Combo-Edit-Box-Progress-Control-On-ToolBar-CToolBar-VC-Example.htm